# wonder why my cable have this split on?

Tags: cable-management

a few day ago i notice that my computer got hack! so i have to reboot my computer and reinstall everything. then i when down stair and check on the cable and notic that there was a split. main cable from outside is connected to my apparment and the other appartment witch confuse me, since usally each apparment has there owwn cable that come from the outside. here a picture of what im trying to said. am i being hack?? or get steal from?? 
https://blu174.mail.live.com/att/GetAttachment.aspx?tnail=0&messageId=898f1b51-764d-11e3-a59d-001e0bcc07ce&Aux=14|0|8D0D87175256910||0|0|0|0||&cid=f320278f9f62d799&maxwidth=220&maxheight=160&size=Att&blob=MHx3aGF0IHRoaXMuZGlifGltYWdlL3BuZw_3d_3d

please email me back if u have any info about it thanks alot!!

Comment: Please attach your comment using the "image" button in the editor here. You've posted a link to something that is not accessible (except to you).

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect your cable connection is being diverted or stolen, contact your cable provider at once and report it. If you look at your cable bill, usually in the fine print or on the back there will be instructions on how to report theft of services.

If not, visit their website and search for "report theft". You can call their main telephone number and try to speak to a person. Once you can get a person and explain the problem to them.

If that doesn't work, visit their nearest office during business hours and state your problem to an employee. Once you have their attention they should take it seriously since they are potentially being stolen from.

Comment: and, FWIW, if the cable is spliced PRIOR to the cable modem, odds are they aren't 'hacking' via that method.